# Using Shopping Cart ID to customize experience

Tags: magento, woocommerce, cartridge

I am looking for a platform to accomplish one goal. I want customers to be able to build a cart with products and then share the cart id so my client (i.e. the business owner) can build the order in the store. They wouldn't be able to check out online, but we will be able to build their order for quick pickup. Any ideas about which platform is the best option?

Answer (score 0):

Using Magento you can do that.

Magento have wishlist functionality and a customer can share his/her wishlist to friends.

Using the same idea , a separate extension will be create to add the products and share it with the site owner immediately via email.

Comment: I haven't explored Magento before, but I applied for a demo account. Thank you. I'll give it a try tonight.